# Excel how to SUM a column filled with Yes's and No's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not summing numbers, but rather the number of occurrences of a keyword.

How is that done?

Sample Data:

```
Item  Completed
---------------
a     No
b     No
c     Yes
d     Yes
e     No

Total Completed: ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B5,"Yes")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CountIf` function.

Syntax: `=CountIf(range, "Yes")`

Comment: I think you need to use`"` instead of `'`...

Comment: @PeterAlbert you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIF` function.
The `COUNTIF` function counts the number of cells within a range that meet a single criterion that you specify.

as per your reference the syntax should be...

> `Syntax: =COUNTIF(<RANGE>,"Yes")`
>
> `Eg.: =COUNTIF(B2:B25,"Yes")`